MongoDB ConfigMap Not Mounting at /etc/mongod.conf in Kubernetes Pod
I'm trying to set up a MongoDB StatefulSet in Kubernetes, and I'm using a ConfigMap to mount the mongod.conf file into the container at /etc/mongod.conf.
I've created the ConfigMap as follows:
kubectl create configmap mongo-config --from-file=mongod.conf

In my StatefulSet configuration (mongo-config.yaml), I'm specifying the volume mount like this:
volumeMounts:
  - name: mongo-config-storage
    mountPath: /data/db
  - name: mongo-config-file
    mountPath: /etc/mongod.conf
    subPath: mongod.conf

The relevant part of the volumes section in the StatefulSet is:
volumes:
  - name: mongo-config-file
    configMap:
      name: mongo-config

When I create the StatefulSet, the pod goes into CrashLoopBackOff, and when I check with a temporary pod (kubectl run -i --tty --rm debug --image=mongo -- bash), I see that /etc/mongod.conf doesn’t exist. Instead, I see a file named /etc/mongod.conf.orig.
What I've Tried:
Verified the ConfigMap was created correctly.
Checked the volume mounts in the pod description.
Confirmed the paths and names in the StatefulSet configuration.
mongo-config.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-config-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    role: mongo-config

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo-config
spec:
  serviceName: "mongo-config-service"
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: mongo-config
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo-config
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: myregistrykey
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo:latest
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--config"
            - "/etc/mongod.conf"   
            - "--configsvr"
            - "--replSet"
            - "configReplSet"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-config-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
            - name: mongo-config-file
              mountPath: /etc/mongod.conf
              subPath: mongod.conf  
      volumes:
        - name: mongo-config-file
          configMap:
            name: mongo-config
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: mongo-config-storage
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi

Questions:
Why might the ConfigMap not be mounting at /etc/mongod.conf as expected?
Do I need to ensure /etc/mongod.conf exists beforehand, or should the ConfigMap handle this automatically?
Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you.

In general I suggest not mixing command line options and config file. Better use only one of them.

Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit for your comment. Can you suggest any way to solve my problem?

This should work (mountPath as simply a directory not the file itself) :
volumeMounts:
- name: mongo-config-storage
  mountPath: /data/db
- name: mongo-config-file
  mountPath: /etc


thanks @shakthi-thillai for answer. I need to know should I use 'subPath' for 'mongo-config-file' volume
